# How to trigger list box data source item added/removed event

Tags: c#, listbox, controls

I am making an online chat room using C# Windows Form. I am currently updating the list box items using data source via a timer.

```
    private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          OnlineUsers = remoteObj.GetOnlineUser(); // ArrayList
          lstOnlineUser.DataSource = OnlineUsers; 
    }
```

All works good. However, I'd like to extend this so that I can create a custom User Control that displays the online users names.

The problem is: How can I remove/add the user control when the user is online or left the chat room without using the data source?

What have I tried:

- ObservableCollection - Instead of ArrayList so that I could use the CollectionChanged event - Not quite sure how this is implented
- Removing all User controls and recreating via timer (Laggy)

I'm looking for an event that is triggered when the ArrayList is updated/removed. Such as something like this:

```
    private void OnlineUsers_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            UserUC User = new UserUC(e.NewItems[0].ToString()); // Not sure if the 'NewItems' list contains the newly added users
        }
        else if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
             // Not sure how I would go about removing
        }
    }
```

Obviously the ArrayList doesn't contain such thing that's why I tried the ObservableCollection instead.

Here are the methods:

```
public class RemotingObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    ArrayList OnlineUsers = new ArrayList();

    public bool JoinToChatRoom(string name)
    {
        if (OnlineUsers.IndexOf(name) > -1)
            return false;
        else
        {
            OnlineUsers.Add(name);
            SendMsgToSvr(name + ".Hey, I joined the chat room.");
            return true;
        }
    }
    public void LeaveChatRoom(string name)
    {
        OnlineUsers.Remove(name);
        SendMsgToSvr(name + "Goodbye, I left the chat room.");
    }
    public ArrayList GetOnlineUser()
    {
        return OnlineUsers;
    }
```

}

I hope you understand and thank you for reading!

Comment: `ObservableCollection - Instead of ArrayList so that I could use the CollectionChanged event - No luck` What does `No luck` mean?

Comment: It means 5 hours of swearing, giving up and head banging pmsl

Comment: *Some* collections would have events such as `AddingNew` and `ListChanged` on the `BindingList`.  If you add/remove to the collection there is no need to bludgeon the control by setting it on a Timer.  A `DataTable` has some events as well as the `BindingSource`